Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Rejected' to data type int
Error message is:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Rejected' to data type int

and SSMS says its occurring on line 65, which would be line 5 in this excerpt.
There's more code above, but figured I'd start here:
CREATE TABLE #excepts (Id INT, [Timestamp] DATETIME, [ShiftName] INT, [MessageBody] NVARCHAR(500))

INSERT INTO #excepts
EXEC (@sqlCommand);

SELECT d.ShiftName, d.Exception, d.[Accepted/Rejected], COUNT(*) AS 'Amount'
FROM (
    SELECT els.[Timestamp], els.[ShiftName], 'Assign' AS 'Exception', 'Accepted' AS 'Accepted/Rejected'
    FROM #excepts els
    WHERE els.MessageBody LIKE '%entered Assign.'
    AND els.Id + 6 IN (
        SELECT Id
        FROM #excepts el
        WHERE el.MessageBody LIKE '%Accepted%'
    ))d

    GROUP BY 
    d.[ShiftName],
    d.[Exception], 
    d.[Accepted/Rejected]

    UNION ALL

    SELECT els.[Timestamp], els.[ShiftName], 'Assign', 'Rejected'
    FROM #excepts  els
    WHERE els.MessageBody LIKE '%entered Assign%'
    AND els.Id + 6 IN (
        SELECT Id
        FROM #excepts el
        WHERE el.MessageBody LIKE '%Ignored%'
    )
        
    UNION ALL

    SELECT els.[Timestamp], els.[ShiftName], 'FULL', 'accepted'
    FROM #excepts  els
    WHERE els.MessageBody LIKE '%entered FULL%'
    AND els.Id + 4 IN (
        SELECT Id
        FROM #excepts el
        WHERE el.MessageBody LIKE '%Accepted%'
    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT els.[Timestamp], els.[ShiftName], 'FULL', 'rejected'
    FROM #excepts  els
    WHERE els.MessageBody LIKE '%entered FULL%'
    AND els.Id + 4 IN (
        SELECT Id
        FROM #excepts el
        WHERE el.MessageBody LIKE '%Ignored%'
    )

    UNION ALL
        
    SELECT els.[Timestamp], els.[ShiftName], 'Arrive', 'accepted'
    FROM #excepts  els
    WHERE els.MessageBody LIKE '%entered Arrive.%'
    AND els.Id + 6 IN (
        SELECT Id
        FROM #excepts el
        WHERE el.MessageBody LIKE '%Accepted%'
    )

    UNION ALL

enter image description here

When you asked your question, you were told "Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and not as images), and format them appropriately." Please follow the instructions when posting your questions, as otherwise you are likely to receive down and/or close votes; meaning your question is far less likely to be answered.

what is d.[Accepted/Rejected] ? probably you want d.[Accepted] / d.[Rejected]

Your query appears to be incomplete. Please take the time to provide us with a full [mre] with DDL and DML

Finally, SSMS is just an IDE (like) application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine? Tagging [[tag:SSMS]] for your data engine is like tagging [[tag:visual-studio]] for your programming language; it doesn't actually really tell us anything.

AS 'Exception' -> Please don't use single quotes to delimit entities. Use [square brackets] or, if you really want to make people think they are string literals, at least use "double quotes". Better yet, avoid keywords.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide-and-conquer_algorithm

It looks like you have your UNION ALLs in the wrong place.
Your indentation is misleading. Look at the parenthesis. Your first (outer) unioned query is yielding ShiftName, Exception, [Accepted/Rejected], and Amount, while the remaining unioned queries are yielding Timestamp, ShiftName, unnamed-literal-string, and unnamed-literal-string.  Amount is an int in the first query, while the matching unnamed literal string 'Rejected' in the second query is not.
Try moving the ) d and GROUP BY to the end of the entire query.
SELECT d.ShiftName, d.Exception, d.[Accepted/Rejected], COUNT(*) AS Amount
FROM (

    SELECT els.Timestamp, els.ShiftName, 'Assign' AS Exception, 'Accepted' AS [Accepted/Rejected]
    FROM #excepts els
    WHERE els.MessageBody LIKE '%entered Assign.'
    AND els.Id + 6 IN (
        SELECT Id
        FROM #excepts el
        WHERE el.MessageBody LIKE '%Accepted%'
    )

    UNION ALL

    SELECT els.[Timestamp], els.[ShiftName], 'Assign', 'Rejected'
    FROM #excepts  els
    WHERE els.MessageBody LIKE '%entered Assign%'
    AND els.Id + 6 IN (
        SELECT Id
        FROM #excepts el
        WHERE el.MessageBody LIKE '%Ignored%'
    )
        
    UNION ALL

    ...
) d
GROUP BY 
    d.ShiftName,
    d.Exception, 
    d.[Accepted/Rejected]

See this db<>fiddle for a demo.

Good catch, this is why consistent indentation is important in sql server
